# Cannot get function to access members of struct

Tags: c++, struct

I'm trying to use one function to calculate an answer using variables stored in a struct. Whenever I compile the code I am getting errors concerning every use of the struct members. Where am I going wrong with this?

Cheers!

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct rectangle 
{

    double length, width, area, perimeter; // measurements for rectangle

};

int calculations() 
{

rect.area = rect.width * rect.length;

rect.perimeter = rect.width + rect.width + rect.length + rect.length; 

}

 int main() 
{  

rectangle rect; // rect is a rectnagle structure 

cout << "Please enter the length of your rectangle: " << endl; 
cin >> rect.length;
cout << "Please enter the width of your rectnagle: " << endl; 
cin >> rect.width; 

calculations();

cout << "The area of your rectangle is: " << rect.area << endl; 

cout << "The perimieter of your rectnagle is: " << rect.perimeter << endl; 

cout << rect.length << endl;
cout << rect.width << endl; 
cout << rect.area << endl; 
cout << rect.perimeter << endl;  

}
```

The errors which are generated are:

```
Untitled.cpp:15:5: error: use of undeclared identifier 'rect'
rect.area = rect.width * rect.length;
^
Untitled.cpp:15:17: error: use of undeclared identifier 'rect'
rect.area = rect.width * rect.length;
            ^
Untitled.cpp:15:30: error: use of undeclared identifier 'rect'
rect.area = rect.width * rect.length;
                         ^
Untitled.cpp:17:5: error: use of undeclared identifier 'rect'
rect.perimeter = rect.width + rect.width + rect.length + rect.length; 
^
Untitled.cpp:17:22: error: use of undeclared identifier 'rect'
rect.perimeter = rect.width + rect.width + rect.length + rect.length; 
                 ^
Untitled.cpp:17:35: error: use of undeclared identifier 'rect'
rect.perimeter = rect.width + rect.width + rect.length + rect.length; 
                              ^
Untitled.cpp:17:48: error: use of undeclared identifier 'rect'
rect.perimeter = rect.width + rect.width + rect.length + rect.length; 
                                           ^
Untitled.cpp:17:62: error: use of undeclared identifier 'rect'
rect.perimeter = rect.width + rect.width + rect.length + rect.length; 
                                                         ^
8 errors generated.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a parameter:

```
void calculations(rectangle& rect) 
{

    rect.area = rect.width * rect.length;

    rect.perimeter = rect.width + rect.width + rect.length + rect.length; 

}
```

And then call:

```
calculations(rect);
```

Comment: This fixes it, thank you! Possibly a silly question, could you tell me the significance of the ampersand after rectangle inside the parameters parentheses?

Comment: @MichaelDelahorne The `&` is here to take the parameter as a [reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_(C%2B%2B)). Without it, the rectangle object would be copied and the modification made inside the calculation function wouldn't impact the rectangle object inside the main. You could also use a pointer `*` to achieve the same thing, or return a new rectangle object depending on your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't declared rect:

```
int calculations() 
{

rect.area = rect.width * rect.length;

rect.perimeter = rect.width + rect.width + rect.length + rect.length; 

}
```

In your example move:

```
rectangle rect; // rect is a rectnagle structure
```

to make it global:

```
};

rectangle rect; // rect is a rectnagle structure 
int calculations() 
{
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void calculations(rectangle &rect) 
{

       rect.area = rect.width * rect.length;

        rect.perimeter = rect.width + rect.width + rect.length + rect.length; 

}
```

try to use this , as there is no rect defined in the scope of  calculation function

Comment: while calling send the parameter as an argument

calculations(rect)

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your function is that it uses name rect that is not global and was defined after the function definition. So the function knows nothing what is rect.

Redefine function as

```
void calculations( rectangle &rect ) 
{
    rect.area = rect.width * rect.length;

    rect.perimeter = rect.width + rect.width + rect.length + rect.length; 
}
```

and call it in main as

```
calculations( rect );
```